# MySQL Constraint check if exist and active

Tags: mysql, constraints

Is there a way to check if the rows already exist and is active?

Let say the rows look like that:

```
ID: 123456

Active : 1
```

I know I could do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id=123456 AND Active=1;
```

But that's not what I want.

And if I try to insert a query into the table again with the same information it should not duplicate.

But the constraint should work if it's not active (0).

I don't want to do the verification code wise. I would like the database server to do the verification.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand. Do you want to _permit_ the `INSERT` if `ID` is duplicated and `Active = 0` while forbidding the insert if `ID` is duplicated and `Active = 1`? In that case, if several rows were inserted per ID with `Active = 0` and multiple `Active` were updated to `1` for a single `ID`, would it violate a constraint?

Comment: I want to make sure the id isn't active before I insert one. If the id is active then the insert shouldn't work. But if the id isn't active(0) then the insert should work.

Comment: But what about the possibility of inserting _many inactive rows_ for the id? And should those rows be prevented from begin updated to active later? In other words, if many were inserted and `UPDATE tbl SET active = 1 WHERE id=123456 AND active=0` matched 3 rows, would it then be a violation to update all 3 to `active = 1`?

Comment: No because I need to keep track of how many entry that person have. But the person should only have ONE active rows.

Comment: Do you even listening? Michael has a perfectly valid concern.

Comment: I need to keep the rows to keep track of how many rows a user have and I won't update the rows. I will insert only.

Comment: @Jean-Mathieu Any feedback on this ?

Comment: I didn't test it yet. But I just want to know. The trigger will be automatically activated when a insert query to that table get inserted? From my research. I just want to know if that's how it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a trigger before insert to block the insert if and only if there is already an active row.

```
create trigger tr_bi_TableName
before insert on TableName
for each row
begin
  if((select count(*) from TableName where id = new.id and active = 1) > 0) then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is already an active row for this id.';
  end if 
end
```

SQLState 45000  means unhandled user-defined exception.

See [documentaton](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) for more info on signal.